# PHP function calls thumbnail but i want to disable the link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having the following problem:

I'm using a WordPress theme for a client. He wants me to edit the cart page (woocommerce) and the theme uses its own woocommerce functions. My client wants to disable the thumbnail link inside the cart page.

The code is:

```
printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
```

For some reason, whatever i edit/code, the page either turns white or the thumbnail doens't appear anymore, but instead it shows the link, so i can't change %s...

Full PHP code:

```
            <td class="product-thumbnail">
                <?php
                    $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                        echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail );
                    else
                        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
                ?>
            </td>
```

And this is the HTML (inspect element)

```
<td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <a href="FAKELINKFAKELINK"><img width="180" height="180" src="FAKELINKFAKELINK/image.jpg/" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="image-alt"></a>                 </td>
```

Who else had this problem? Or how do i solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to say there is a link on the page and you want it to not show up? If so please show me what the html of the link looks like in the dom. Inspect element and copy and paste the html and link so I can see it.

Comment: Hi Wuno

I edited my question, please take a look!

Comment: Ok cool look at the body tag. show me the body tag and all the class id that are attached to it.

Comment: What do you mean by bodytags? 

I think you mean this: 

page page-id-1088 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar woocommerce-cart woocommerce-page wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.5.3 vc_responsive customize-support

Comment: I am pretty sure in wordpress the page-id-1088 is a class. make sure to look at it. if it says id ten change it to # instead of . Also we might have to adjust the css a tiny bit to make sure it only removes what you want it to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the link from this page,

```
<td class="product-thumbnail"> 
<?php 
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 

if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) 
echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); 
else 
printf( '<a class="hidden" href="%s"></a>%s', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail ); 
?> 
</td>
```

add this to your `css`

```
.hidden { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wuno, i tried it, but it removes the thumbnail completely, which the client doesn't want. He only wants to remove the link from the thumbnail, but still showing the thumbnail itself, without the link.

Comment: The table row is back, but the thumbnail isn't showing, weird right?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately... the first code you provided deleted the table row, the edited one made the row showing again but without the thumbnail itself...

Comment: Yes! I now see that the url + the thumbnail does exist in the page source, but it isn't showing in the table row. Also, thanks for helping me!